# Asp.Net Boilerplate .Net Core 2.0 AbpAuthorizationFilter - ChallengeResult / Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am running an **Asp.Net Core 2.0** with **Asp.Net Boilerplate version 3.4.0** web application.

When I have an authenticated user that does not have the required permissions to access a resource, a `ChallengeResult` is set by the `AbpAuthorizationFilter` via the **Abp** framework. This behavior results in the user being returned to the default login page.  If the user is authenticated, I would like to set a `ForbidResult` and redirect them to the default AccessDenied page.

After reviewing my options, I see that I have the following options:

1. Add my own authorization filter and register with the `MvcOptions` prior to the `AddAbp()` service configuration. The filter would conditionally set the result to Challenge or Forbid
2. Override the `OnRedirectToLogin` event ( i.e., customize for authenticated users )
3. Override the `HandleChallengeAsync` handler ( i.e., check to see if the request is authenticated and issue ForbidResult or ChallengeResult for unauthenticated requests)

I noticed in the .Net framework version of ABP, that there are overridable methods in the `AbpMvcAuthorizeFilter` (i.e., `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`) ; however, this does not apply to the .Net Core version. See GitHub Issue 1256 -> 
[Make AbpMvcAuthorizeFilter and AbpApiAuthorizeFilter overridable](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1256)

### Question:

Has anyone else needed to change the default **Abp** behavior of returning a `ChallengeResult` for unauthorized requests? If yes, what solution did you use? Did I missing something in the **Abp** configuration or Asp.Net Core ( other than the three options listed above) that would provide me more control of this behavior?

If I go with a workaround, it feels kind of a like a hack to control this behavior.

### Option 1:

Out of the three options that I listed, option *one* seems the cleanest and most appropriate place to handle this logic. It's not pretty either as I would be copying the entire `AbpAuthorizationFilter` to only change a few lines of code.

*Current Code:*

```
context.Result = new ChallengeResult();
```

*Proposed Change:*

```
if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //User is already logged in.. No need to redirect to the 
    //login page
    context.Result = new ForbidResult();
}
else
{
    context.Result = new ChallengeResult();
}
```

Full code below:

[AbpAuthorizationFilter.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Authorization/AbpAuthorizationFilter.cs) See Catch block lines - 58 - 77

### Option 2:

Option two feels *kludgy* because the logic that I would introduce into the `OnRedirectToLogin` event would have to make an assumption that an authenticated user has attempted to access an unauthorized resource. Currently, I only see the `Events.RedirectToLogin` being raised in the `CookieAuthenticationHandler` via the `HandleChallengeAsync` method. With that being said it feels safe to assume that this event would only be raised by a `ChallengeResult` result. [CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L441)

### Option 3:

Option three would be the last option( i.e., avoided at all costs)

### Main Goal

The main goal is to provide a better experience for authenticated users attempting to access unauthorized resources. Rather than redirecting the user to the login page, the user should be redirected to an unauthorized / forbidden page that clearly indicates that they are not authorized. This might include an option to prompt the user to provide higher privileged credentials. By prompting the user, it smells like a `ChallengeResult` result flow so maybe I just answered my own question. With the current behavior, I don't have much context information on *"why"* the `ChallengeResult` was issued. I will know that the user is logged in and that the `OnRedirectToLogin` event was raised. This is probably enough info to customize the behavior of the `ChallengeResult` for authenticated users.  This is starting to feel like this is the correct solution. Any suggestions or feedback on using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the three options, I went with option number two ( override the `OnRedirectToLogin`event) for the following reasons:

1. Minimal code introduced without duplicating an entire authorization filter to only change two lines of code.
2. More control of the challenge experience ( the MVC app is an OIDC client too ) with its own set of roles and permissions ( see code solution below )
3. At the time of this response, the `OnRedirectToLogin` event is only raised by the `HandleChallengeAsync` in the [CookieAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L441) so this feels like the correct place to override the `ChallengeResult` behavior.

**Solution:**

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        //The user is not authenticated... Use the "oidc" challenge scheme 
        //and send them to identity server.
        var task = context.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc");
        task.WaitAndUnwrapException();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    var accessDeniedPath = BuildRedirectUri(context.HttpContext, options.AccessDeniedPath);

    context.Response.Redirect(accessDeniedPath);
    context.Response.StatusCode = 302;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

**Side Note:**

It should be noted that the default behavior of the `AbpAuthorizationFilter` does not mirror the stock behavior of Asp.Net Core MVC 2.0 `AuthorizeFilter`. When authorization fails for an authenticated user, the Asp.Net Core MVC 2.0 `AuthorizeFilter` returns a Forbid result.

Asp.Net Core MVC's default `AuthorizeFilter` delegates the authorization to the  `IPolicyEvaluator`. If the authorization fails and the user is authenticated, a Forbid result is set or if the authorization fails and the user is not-authenticated, a Challenge result is set.

[PolicyEvaluator.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L91)

```
var result = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.User, resource, policy);
if (result.Succeeded) 
{ 
    return PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success(); 
} 

// If authentication was successful, return forbidden, otherwise challenge 
return (authenticationResult.Succeeded)  
    ? PolicyAuthorizationResult.Forbid()  
    : PolicyAuthorizationResult.Challenge();
```