# Stop Page Authentication redirecting to Login page if fails

Tags: authentication, aspnetboilerplate

So I've set up some roles/permissions in my site and when testing pages that the current user does not have permission to view they get redirected to the Login page but instead I want an error message/page saying they are forbidden from viewing that page.

I've tried the solution in : [Asp.Net Boilerplate .Net Core 2.0 AbpAuthorizationFilter - ChallengeResult / Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027406/asp-net-boilerplate-net-core-2-0-abpauthorizationfilter-challengeresult-una) but that does not seem to have done anything.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this behavior in `auth-route-guard.ts` that is in `angular/src/shared/auth/auth-route-guard.ts`

`AppRouteGuard` intercepts all routes, here's the file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PermissionCheckerService } from 'node_modules/abp-ng2-module/dist/src/auth/permission-checker.service';
import { AppSessionService } from '../session/app-session.service';

import {
    CanActivate, Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    CanActivateChild
} from '@angular/router';
import { AlertasHelper } from '../helpers/alertas-helper';

@Injectable()
export class AppRouteGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    constructor(
        private _permissionChecker: PermissionCheckerService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _sessionService: AppSessionService,
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

        if (!this._sessionService.user) {
            this._router.navigate(['/account/login']);
            return false;
        }

        if (!route.data || !route.data['permission']) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this._permissionChecker.isGranted(route.data['permission'])) {
            return true;
        }

        this._router.navigate([this.selectBestRoute()]);
        return false;
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }

    selectBestRoute(): string {
        if (!this._sessionService.user) {
            return '/account/login';
        }

        if (this._permissionChecker.isGranted('Pages.Users')) {
            return '/app/admin/users';
        }

        AlertasHelper.show('Usuario no tiene autorización', 'Sin autorización');
        return '/dashboard/analytics';
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have the `selectBestRoute()` method if a user is not autorized to see the page you can set there the message or the page you want to show

see this

```
 if (!this._sessionService.user) {
     return '/account/login';
 }
```

if `_sessionService.user` is undefinied then will return to /account/login.

`selectBestRoute()` method is called from `canActivate()` method which is specified on your routes

Here is an example

```
{
    path: 'country',
    data: { permission: 'Aplicacion.Generales.Country' },
    canActivate: [AppRouteGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./country/country.module').then(module => module.CountryModule)
},
```

Before `CountryModule` is called will be verified on [AppRouteGuard]

I hope it could help you.